# How do I fix "Your profile could not be opened correctly" in Chrome on a Mac?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, user-profiles

The full error message is:

> Your profile could not be opened correctly. Some features may be unavailable.  Please check that the profile exists and you have permission to read and write its contents.

My bookmarks appear to have been retained, but all of the favicons for them are gone. What did I do? Anyone know how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just removed `rm -rf Web\ Data` from `~/.config/chromium/Default`.

Plus had to restart computer.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is an issue with a corrupted file; so unfortunately you will have to delete the currently set google profile in Google Chrome.

1. Quit Google Chrome.
2. Open Terminal.
3. Change directory (`cd`) to `/Users/{user}/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`
4. Delete Web Data and History files:  `rm -rf History*; rm -rf Web\ Data;`
5. Start Google Chrome and the error should be gone.

Please see the link below for complete instructions:

http://www.fourleaftechnology.com/index.php/General/google-chrome-profile-could-not-be-opened-correctly-error.html

Comment: Strangely enough, that didn't do the trick but when I deleted the entire /Application Support/Google/Chrome folder and reinstalled Chrome it worked.

Comment: That's great! :)

Comment: Has the same issue with Opera, this solved it

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was to completely uninstall Chrome, then reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Much easier than any of this .......**uncheck** 'Let chrome run in background' close and restart chrome .....The cause is that your profile is still running in bg and multi instances of same user is a nogo